# How can I escape single quotes for Ansible/Jinja2 ternary operator?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the snippet below. Basically, for an included task I would like to provide a variable whose contents look like the below string:

```
--date='something'
```

or it should be empty if the original variable is an empty string. The thing is, I need the string to be in the form above, including the single quotes around the value.

If I wouldn't need the single quotes, everything works perfectly! However, as I need them, I am trying to escape them using the below snippet. Unfortunately, what I have doesn't seem to work, as \' doesn't apply as expected. How can I properly escape ' so that get them in my string?

```
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: ../tasks/get_current.yml
    - include_tasks: ../tasks/failed_jobs_stats.yml
      vars:
        date_param: "{{ date_start != '' | ternary('--date=\''+date_start+'\'', '') }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a quoting problem, this is an operator precedence problem.

In your example, you:

1. apply the ternary filter to the empty string `''`
2. compare the above result to `date_start`

---

What you need to do is to enclose the condition in parens:

```
date_param: "{{ (date_start != '') | ternary('--date=\''+date_start+'\'', '') }}"
```